# Only affect the styling of a component in which the style has been imported?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, less

I have a less file defined as follows:

```
//style.less
.ant-modal-close-x
{
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

IN a component class I use it as such:

```
//testclass.tsx
import './style.less';

class ReactComp{
 render(){
     return <Modal>abc</Modal>
   }
}
```

Now for some context: Modal is an ant.design modal dialogue, it contains a close button which uses the class name 'ant-modal-close-x' for its styling.

Because I've included 'style.less' in testclass.tsx it now affects ALL components including others which use Modal where I don't want the styling of the close button to be affected.

Is there a way to specifically override styles per component?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was appropriate to put the css tag on this but the issue happens if I use style.css as well.. I would think the solution for less and css would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

No sooner than had I posted this question after hours of trying to make this work I realised the solution:

In style.less I do the following:

```
.popup .ant-modal-close-x
{
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

Then in testclass.tsx in the render function:

```
render() {
   return <Modal className="popup">test</Modal>
}
```

Comment: Asking questions has a habit of making you think through what you're trying to accomplish to find a solution hehe.

I won't mark this as the answer in case someone has a more elegant solution where the imported style is imported on demand per component rather than globally.